# FPDI with Multiple Pages

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I am new to PHP and am having a bit of a hard time with using FPDI when it comes to inserting multiple pages.

I have a .pdf file which consists of 3 pages.
I ended up saving page 1 as a separate page out of the 3 and that worked with my code, but that is because my code is meant only for 1 page. When I change it back to the 3 page file, it gives me an internal server error.

This is the code which I am using:

```
<?php

require_once('prog/fpdf.php');
require_once('prog/fpdi.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI();

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// set the source file
$pdf->setSourceFile("apps/Par.pdf");

// import page 1
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);

// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 100 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, null, null, 0, 0, true);

// font and color selection
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(200, 0, 0);

// now write some text above the imported page
$pdf->SetXY(40, 83);
$pdf->Write(2, 'THIS IS JUST A TEST');


$pdf->Output();
```

I am not sure how to turn this code into having the ability to see all 3 pages.
Please help me out who ever can.

Answer (score 27):

The [setSourceFile()](http://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/the-fpdi-class/#index-3-1) method will return the page count of the document you'd set.
Just loop through this pages and import them page by page. You example for all pages would look like:

```
<?php
require_once('prog/fpdf.php');
require_once('prog/fpdi.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI();

// set the source file
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile("apps/Par.pdf");

for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, null, null, 0, 0, true);

    // font and color selection
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
    $pdf->SetTextColor(200, 0, 0);

    // now write some text above the imported page
    $pdf->SetXY(40, 83);
    $pdf->Write(2, 'THIS IS JUST A TEST');
}

$pdf->Output();
```

Regarding the "internal server" you should enable your error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

...or simply check your php error logs for details.

Comment: Update: On the latest version of FPDI (2.2) the order of parameters of `useTemplate()` changed. Use: `$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, null, null, true);`

Comment: @Havenard: It's not the order but the default values as documentated [here](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/migrating/#index-7). IIRC internally this doesn't make a change at all? In v2 you also can pass an array of options now, so that it will look like `$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, ['adjustPageSize' => true]);`

Comment: Well I post this because it does make a difference, FPDI throws a fatal error because `x` and `y` cannot be `null` (`width` and `height` can). -- At least in the Composer version of the library, I noticed there are variants and didn't test them.

Comment: @Havenard: You're right! This was a BC change - that's why we documentated it in the migration guide.

Comment: I have a related issue.  I have a 1-x page document, and sometimes I need to print out 2 copies of the document, with some of the content static and the other dynamic.  I sort of know how to do that, but looking for a way to append a second copy of my PDF document to the original.

Comment: @SScotti Nothing stops you from doing this (just restart your iteration). If you have a problem with your code, open a new question and please don't use a comment on an answer for a new question.

Comment: @JanSlabon  Thanks.  Actually figured out how to deal with that.  A little complicated because I have documents that can have 1-n pages, and then 1-n copies of each document.  Works OK though.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

It works for me:

```
<?php

require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi/src/autoload.php');

use \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

$pdf = new FPDI();
// get the page count
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('pdf_file.pdf');
// iterate through all pages
for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
    // import a page
    $templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
    // get the size of the imported page
    $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);

    // create a page (landscape or portrait depending on the imported page size)
    if ($size[0] > $size[1]) {
        $pdf->AddPage('L', array($size[0], $size[1]));
    } else {
        $pdf->AddPage('P', array($size[0], $size[1]));
    }

    // use the imported page
    $pdf->useTemplate($templateId);

    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
    $pdf->SetXY(5, 5);
    $pdf->Write(8, 'A complete document imported with FPDI');
}

$pdf->Output();
```

Change array($size['w'], $size['h']) for array($size[0], $size[1])

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi/fpdi.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI();

// get the page count
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('Laboratory-Report.pdf');
// iterate through all pages
for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
// import a page
$templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
// get the size of the imported page
$size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);

// create a page (landscape or portrait depending on the imported page size)
if ($size['w'] > $size['h']) {
    $pdf->AddPage('L', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
} else {
    $pdf->AddPage('P', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
}

// use the imported page
$pdf->useTemplate($templateId);

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetXY(5, 5);
$pdf->Write(8, 'A complete document imported with FPDI');
}

// Output the new PDF
$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by old solution but here i am explaining how to use it.

```
# Add 2 page
$pdf->AddPage(); 
$tplIdx2 = $pdf->importPage(2);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx2); 
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 5); # optional line
```

here you have to note that i am adding **AddPage()** code that adds new page into PDF. Add Page always comes first. it is required.

**importPage(Page_number)** imports a page into current page of PDF.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked perfectly for me. Laravel implementation. And this only writes on the page you want not every page**

```
use setasign\Fpdf\Tpdf\Fpdf;
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

class SignDocumentsController extends Controller
{
    public function signPDF(Request $data)
    {
        
        $pdf = new Fpdi();
        
        $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($data["sourceFile"]);
        
        for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
            $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 5, 5, 205);

            $pdf->SetFont('Times');
            $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
            
            if($pageNo==$data["pageNumber"]){
                $pdf->Image($data["signitureImg"],$data["x"],$data["y"],$data["w"],$data["h"],$data["pictureType"]);
                $x = $data["x"]+1;
                $y = $data["y"]+$data["h"]+1;
                $pdf->SetXY($x,$y);
                $pdf->Write(0, date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
            }
            $filename=$data["outputFile"];
        }
        $pdf->Output($filename,'F');
        
        return response()->json([

            "success"=>true,
            "responseBody" => [
                "change_status" =>"Success"
            ]
                    ], 201);

        

    }

}
```

**The json post request data is:**

```
{
    "sourceFile":"/home/courage/Documents/TM 2020.pdf",
    "outputFile":"/home/courage/Documents/Signed.pdf",
    "pageNumber":"3",
    "signitureImg":"/home/courage/Downloads/signature.png",
    "x":"85",
    "y":"230",
    "w":"30",
    "h":"11",
    "pictureType":"png"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. This works for me.

```
$pdf = new Fpdi();

$sourceFilePages = $pdf->setSourceFile($sourceFile);

    for($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $sourceFilePages; $pageNo++){

        $template = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);

        $pdf->AddPage();
       
        // $adjustPageSize needs to be set to true if you need to have the original PDF page dimensions 
        $pdf->useTemplate($template, 0, 0, null, null, true);


        if ($stampFirstPageOnly){
            if ($pageNo == 1){
                // stamping only the first page
                $pdf->Image($stampFile, stampXCoord, $stampYCoords, $stampWidth, $stampHeight);
            }
        }
        else{
            // stamping all the pages
            $pdf->Image($stampFile, $stampXCoord, $stampYCoords, $stampWidth, $stampHeight);
        }
    }

// pdfOutputMethod "I" -> Browser Inline, "D" -> Force Download, "F" -> Save to Disk
$pdf->Output($pdfOutputMethod, $fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional to determine the PDF sheet format in Portrait or landscape form

```
require_once('prog/fpdf.php');
require_once('prog/fpdi.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI();

// set the source file
$fileInput = "apps/Par.pdf";
$pages_count = $pdf->setSourceFile($fileInput); 
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages_count; $i ++) {

   $pdf->setSourceFile($fileInput);
   $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($i);
   $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tplIdx);
        
   if ((int)$size[0] > (int)$size[1]) {
      $pdf->AddPage('L');
   }else{
      $pdf->AddPage('P');
   } 

   // use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 100 mm
   $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, null, null, 0, 0, true);

   // font and color selection
   $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
   $pdf->SetTextColor(200, 0, 0);

   // now write some text above the imported page
   $pdf->SetXY(40, 83);
   $pdf->Write(2, 'THIS IS JUST A TEST');

}
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).